# transform all the pdfs in a folder to text and process these txt files

Tags: linux, bash

I have to transform all the pdfs in a folder to text files and apply two operations to those text files, one to remove certain words and the second to leave a record in a single line, the part of the script that does the latter says that there is no text file, but if  is created to be transferred from pdf to text, but does not recognize it.

```
full_string=$1
search_string="pdf"
replace_string="txt"
my_string=${full_string/$search_string/$replace_string}
pdftotext -layout $1 > $my_string
cat $my_string | sed -e "/REPUBLICA/,/NOMBRE.*SEXO.*MESA$/d" > $my_string
cat $my_string | sed -e "N;N;N;N; s/\n  */ /; P; D" > $my_string
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question (yes, i did notice, there isn't actually a question here :P)? "part of the script" etc. I think your problem might be that you're `cat`ing a file and writing to it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
cat $my_string | sed -e "/REPUBLICA/,/NOMBRE.*SEXO.*MESA$/d" > $my_string
```

the redirection overwrites your `$my_string` with an empty file, before the `cat` is done.

You will probably want to use

```
sed -i -e "N;N;N;N; s/\n  */ /; P; D"  $my_string
```

Comment: The OP probably wants to do the same for the first `sed` command as well.